# Is normal to store different type of objects inside a collection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a collection that can hold different types of objects. For example, a Car object can have some fields that are totally different than a Flower object. I don't want to create a collection of cars for example, that will hold only Car objects, I need a collection that contains a mix of objects. Can this be a problem? Can this affect the performance is any way, since the objects are of different types and not of a single type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a collection that contains a mix of objects. Can this be a
> problem? Can this affect the performance is any way, since the objects
> are of different types and not of a single type?

No, it is not a problem. Documents in a collection can have totally different fields. It has no effect on the performance.

However, multiplying the number of fields in a Collection could, in certain cases (depending on your queries), multiply the number of  composite indexes for a database which, by default, [is limited to 200](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes). Note however that you can contact the support to request an increase to this limit. (And actually this would be the same with different collections...)

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. One more quick question. If the documents have different fields but there is one that is present inside all documents, for example a "price", when I query based on the price, can I return all documents no matter what the type is?

Comment: "when I query based on the price, can I return all documents no matter what the type is?" => Yes